# reading time from screen using pytesseract

Tags: python, time, python-tesseract

I'm trying to read time data from my screen.

If the time is like "0:15", "0:35" (minutes : seconds) or something its working fine.

But if time is 1 minute ("1:00") i get an error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Doesnt tesseract read it properly or is it my code?

````
        timeText = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            timeImg, lang='eng', config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789,: -c page_separator=''')
        seperatedTime = timeText.split(':')
        minutes = int(seperatedTime[0])
        seconds = int(seperatedTime[1])

        totalSeconds = (minutes*60) + seconds```
````

Comment: You should do some debugging by printing timeText and separatedTime - their values are clearly not what you expect

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In an example with the time 0:30 my timeText is '0:30' and my seperatedTime is ['0', '30\n'] except the '\n' it is what i was expecting. If my timeImg is 1:00 the timeText is empty.

Comment: If your timeText sometimes has a value, sometimes not, it must be the ocr that is failing. It is beyond my knowledge how to improve that.